# using computer to solve a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, computational-mathematics

I was wondering if there is a program or website that solved a system of nonlinear equations
I was trying a system that looks like this
$$a+b = cd , a+c = bd ,a+d = bc$$
, ...
it's like a pattern
that share the idea of
For all sets S⊆U such that $|S|=m$ and $|U|=2m $ , $$∏_{i∈S} qi = \sum_{i∈U∖S} qi $$

Comment: Yes, there are many CAS you can use: for emxaple [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/), mathematica, maple, GAP, sage, reduce, singular etc., see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). Please include your equations. We may be able to solve them immediately. Use variables $x_i$ for simplicity.

Comment: @DietrichBurde
sry about my Q not being clear I added the problem I was trying to solve

Comment: So the variables are $a,b,c,d,\ldots $, and the solutions is sought in integers? What is the domain for solving $a+b=cd$, etc ? Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You should first try for small $m$.

Comment: @Moo
thx for help the problem with wolfram that is solve only 4 equations 
I was trying to solve 6 equations to find the pattern to the problem I just added

Comment: @DietrichBurde 
yes the solution is integers

Comment: yes Exactly,
i wanted to know the sol. for this problem where m = 2 , m =3 to notice if there is a common pattern that may help me with the solution

Comment: @DietrichBurde
at the end, I solve it by hand I know but it took a while 
so I was wondering if there is a tool to help 
there was a typo at the eqs. I rewrote it sry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of equations
$$a+b = cd , a+c = bd ,a+d = bc$$
has the solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ as follows:
$$
(-b-1,b,-1,-1),\; (1-d,-1,-1,d),\; (1-c,-1,c,-1),\;(d(d-1),d,d,d).
$$
This already shows a pattern.

Comment: thanks for helping that helped me to solve this problem but I was wondering if there a tool that solves it for large m or any other constraints so I find the pattern faster if I face a problem similar to this

Comment: Yes, you can use a CAS. However, not all systems of polynomial equations can be solved so easily, in particular not over the integers.

Comment: ok thx so much <3